# Tesseract OCR loading a language - Japanese

Tags: tesseract

I just installed Tesseract OCR and after running the command `$ tesseract --list-langs` the output showed only 2 languages, `eng` and `osd`. My question is, how do I load another language, in my case specifically, Japanese?

Comment: can you please share what solved your problem? I am working on similar issue.

Answer (score 5):

I learned that by grabbing the trained data from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata and placing it in the same directory as the other trained data, i.e., `eng.traineddata` and by passing the language flag `-l LANG` tesseract should be able to read the language you've specified, in the following example, Japanese: `tesseract -l jpn sample-jpn.png output-jpn`.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-jpn
```

hope [this will help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793634/how-do-i-install-a-new-language-pack-for-tesseract-on-16-04).

Comment: Copying the german language model (deu.traineddata) into the `tessdata` folder led to `Error opening data file /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/deu.traineddata`. This method solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

```html
1. pip install pytesseract

2. for windows install tesseract-ocr from 
https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract
select all language options while installing

3. set the tesseract-ocr path under anaconda/lib/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py

tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

4. from pytesseract import image_to_string
print(image_to_string(test_file, 'jpn')) #for Japenese text extraction
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, if you had installed tesseract using brew, then:

1. Go to https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata and download https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/main/script/Japanese.traineddata
2. Put the file in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/share/tessdata/`.
3. The language code will be saved under `"Japanese"` or whatever the file name is.